# getPostParameter is not working in symfony 1.2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables, symfony-1.2

problem

- im sending data through ajax

data request payload json sending after form submit

```
 {
 mis_interests[code]:"R"
 mis_interests[date_opened][month]:" 03-Mar-2016 "
 mis_interests[notes]:" test" 
 }
```

- but cannot recieve this data in controller.

js script

```
            var json_data={
            'mis_interests[code]':interests_val,
            'mis_interests[notes]':texts,
            'mis_interests[date_opened][month]':dateoepend
            }

            jQuery.ajax({
            type:'POST',

            url:'<?php  echo url_for('person/UpdateDatatableInterests')?>',

            contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            dataType: "json",

            data:JSON.stringify(json_data),
            success: function(data){

            console.log(data);



            }
            });
            });
```

html fields

```
<form name="something">
<div id="myinterest_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper no-footer">
  <select name="mis_interests[code]" id="mis_interests_code" class="mis_interests_code"><option value="test">test</option></select>
  <td id="notes" name="mis_interests[notes]">test</td>

 <td id="dateopened" name="mis_interests[date_opened][month]">03-Mar-2016    </td>
```

php code

controller action.class.php

```
public function executeUpdateDatatableInterests(sfWebRequest $request)
{

    var_dump($request->getPostParameter('mis_interests[code]'));

     //output :NULL
}
```

- i  need to post value selected from dropdown to controller.
- we are using form , datatable html elements.
- is there any problem in datatable that is sending null values because i created  attribute over datatable that might be culprit.
- any suggestion is most welcome.

when i tried change in controller

like

```
$json = $_POST['mis_interests[code]']; 
var_dump(json_decode($json)); 
it shows notice undefined index mis_interests[code]
```

Comment: You're sending a JSON request. PHP doesn't automatically decode that data to populate the request globals. You should read the raw POST data and decode it. In SF2, you'd use `$data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);`

Comment: when use core concept like $json = $_POST['mis_interests[code]'];

var_dump(json_decode($json)); it shows notice undefined index mis_interests[code]

Comment: Im thinking problem in using ajax with datatable

Comment: No, you're sending a JSON _string_, and expecting a POST array. That doesn't fly. check `var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));`, that should show a JSON string, `json_decode` that to get an array or object, _then_ you can do something like `$decoded['mis_interests']['code']` to get the data

Comment: thanks elias concepts worked